# Graphics card for Fujitsu Primergy tx100 s3p

Tags: graphics-cards, ubuntu

I’m looking for a graphics card compatible with the Fujitsu Primergy tx100 s3p, any recommendations? I will mostly use it for development using Android Studio on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much any card will work, as long as your power supply can handle it.  Are you using the stock power supply, or have you put a new one in?  If you have a new PSU, I like the GTX 650 Ti as a cheaper GPU.  Works pretty well for ~$50 USD used.  What's your budget?

Comment: I'm using the stock power supply. My budget is $200.

Comment: Alright.  I forgot your computer was a server.  Because of this, you'll need an irregular power supply that would be hard to find.  So you'll have to either use adapters (which is generally not a good idea) or get a GT series GPU.  I found a GT 1030 on Amazon for a little less than your budget, but because there is no power input, the performance isn't the best.  It'll run Android Studio just fine, though.
https://www.amazon.com/MSI-GT-1030-2G-LP/dp/B071L4VKF6/